# Knitro`ms_maxsolves` equivalent in Ipopt

Tags: nonlinear-programming, solver, ipopt, interior-point-method, knitro

Ipopt/Knitro are local optimization solvers, so for nonconvex problems convergence doesn't guarantee optimality. However, Knitro has a multi-start [method](https://www.artelys.com/docs/knitro/3_referenceManual/userOptions.html#ms_maxsolves) where one can start with more random initial solutions with the hope of terminating at a better solution than a single run. I am wondering, is there an equivalent `ms_maxsolves` option in Ipopt? I failed finding a suitable option in Ipopt in my research.

Comment: I don't think IPOPT has a multistart option. But if IPOPT is called from Pyomo, you can use Pyomo's multistart capability. https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/SkKSzPfiM-o .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mark-l-stone says, Ipopt does not have a multi-start option. Just solve your model with different starting points manually.